# Different SharePoint Lists with same Columns spaced differently?

Tags: sharepoint-server, list

I have created lists among 8 different sites which have all of the same columns, views, settings, etc. For some reason, one list looks exactly how I want it to spacing/padding wise. All of the others are a lot less spaced apart and I cannot seem to figure out why they are doing so.

I have tried altering the CSS

```
.ms-vb2 {
    padding: 4px 8px 4px 4px;
}
```

and that doesn't do anything. (That styling is how it is on the list that looks how it should.

Here is how they both look:

How its supposed to look:
[image]

How it actually looks:
[image]

Comment: Could it be that the content inside the lists is different? Because of it, the columns appear to have different widths

Comment: Could you share your modified css?If I change the the css,it works well in my environment.

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov thats what I thought at first, then after going through the list settings, the content type is identical, the content in the lists are identical, and the view is identical

Comment: It's not the settings I am talking about. What I meant to say is that the *CONTENT* might be different. For example, a large chunk of text in a column will push this column wider. a column with no content will be narrower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it is not the CSS that is the issue, change the SharePoint list web app from `<Current View>` to `<Summary View>`